# When Updating or Downloading an App on my iPod touch, it Only Appears as "Waiting"

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch 4th gen and the software is all up to date. I've had it for about 14 months, but the other day I was updating quite a few apps (maybe 16 or so) because I hadn't used my iPod touch for awhile. I don't know if this has anything to do with it but at the same time I was downloading some podcasts from the iTunes Store (which was also having some minor problems).

I typed in the passcode then clicked "ok". It took a little longer then normal, but it closed the app store, went to home screen then the screen where all my apps are in files like usual.

Five minutes later I realize that nothing has happened (all the updating apps are on "waiting") so I go back to the App Store and update it again. The same thing happens three more times with no luck. I turned my iPod touch off then on again and try uploading. Still nothing.

A few days later I was trying to update again and then, after the tenth try and three restarts, it started updating.

Two days after that I try updating 3 more apps and it works fine after the second try.

Today I was trying to download Magic Piano from Smule (and I recently got the Glee app so it doesn't seem like there's something wrong with my iPod touch and Smule) and it won't download at all. I've tried restarting, pausing, deleting and re-downloading everything and nothing seems to be working. Right now I have some TV shows downloading onto my iPod touch, is that the problem? Help!

Comment: Anecdotally, there seems to be some instability in the system causing slower downloads and pauses. Have you tried tapping the icon to officially "pause" the download and try resuming this after about 5 and 30 minutes on pause?

Comment: Thank you so much! I noticed that my iTouch lags anyway, even when I'm on an app that doesn't require wifi. Do I just need to replace it?

Comment: Probably just needs a restore and for you to set it up as new. When the device fails, it generally has horrible problems doing anything. Think of the millions of CPU operations per second, if it's not working, things go wrong in a split second. Lagging is almost always software and a restore without using the backup is the fastest route to good, clean software. You can restore your backup later or just add apps and start syncing over the fresh start as you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Requirements:

- [iExplorer (free)](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) for both PC and Mac
- You do **not** need a jailbroken device to do this

Steps:

- Plug your iPod/iPhone/iPad into your computer. You don't need to let it sync
- Open iExplore and let it load
- Open the directory labeled "Downloads" (On jailbroken devices that should be "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads")
- Delete all files in this folder*
- Close iExplore and reboot your device

Answer (score 0):

This method worked perfectly for me when I had this problem. I was suprised how easy and obvious it is.

All you have to do is restart your iPod (shut it down) and it will not lose any data. Hold the sleep button and the home button together until the screen is blank and then the Apple logo appears. Then try downloading something and it will most likely work!